# Win32 Memory Access Exception with 4+ Edittext controls

Tags: c++, c, winapi, win32gui

I am currently working on a project in win32 using Visual Studio 2010. I am encountering a problem where any dialog I have defined in a resource script (.rc) throws a first chance exception after calling CreateDialog IF the specific dialog has more than 3 Edittext's in it. This is consistent across dialogs in the solution.

The memory access error does not cause execution to halt, but it does cause the dialog to not render on the screen. If I add the DS_NOFAILCREATE style flag, the other controls in the dialog will render, but only 3 of the Edittext's will.

When I run the application created from the build process, all of the dialogs render as expected, and it looks like no first chance exceptions are being thrown.

Any clues or insights into this would be very helpful!

What is happening:

```
// in my cpp file
HWND myWnd = CreateDialog( hInst, "MY_DIALOG" , pHwnd, (DLGPROC) DlgProc);

//in the header, this setup works fine in other pars of the project
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

In this example, myWnd is coming back as NULL, with an error code of 0. The handle is null because of a failure during creation, which seems to occur on the 4th Edittext control in the resource script. This causes the dialog to not appear when I call ShowWindow().

I am wondering why the CreateDialog is throwing this error ONLY when there are more than 4 Edittext controls.

Adding the rc file

```
MY_DIALOG DIALOGEX 50, 50, 1000, 1000
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | DS_NOFAILCREATE
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif", 0,0,0x0
BEGIN
    EDITTEXT    IDC_EDIT1, 222, 33, 40, 14 , ES_CENTER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT    IDC_EDIT2, 222, 50, 40, 14 , ES_CENTER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT    IDC_EDIT3, 222, 65, 40, 14 , ES_CENTER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT    IDC_EDIT4, 222, 85, 40, 14 , ES_CENTER | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    etc...
END
```

The error thrown (which does not halt execution) is:

```
First-chance exception at 0x763aa225 in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4c41434f
```

This is thrown 2-3 times PER editbox over the third.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: Please post the problematic dialog definition from your .rc file.

Comment: Why are you passing `hwnd` as the first parameter to `CreateDialog()`? That first parameter is an `HINSTANCE`; it needs to be the `HINSTANCE` passed to `WinMain()` or `DllMain()`. Use `#define STRICT`. Also the cast to `DLGPROC` is suspicious. Fix your dialog procedure signature. What is it?

Comment: The call to CreateDialog works using the same info with other dialogs using the exact same setup. So I'm not worried about my call, and more worried about the dialog itself.

Comment: Try using `DS_CONTROL` in addition to `WS_CHILD`?

Comment: IMO the problem is totally unrelated to the number of editboxes, but happens in the initialization. Could you show us the dialog procedure? Could you also check the error code, using `GetLastError()`, after `CreateDialog()` returns NULL?

Comment: To verify that this is related to the EDIT controls, remove the `etc...` portion of your resource script. Since the dialog manager calls `CreateWindowEx` for each control, you will have to make sure, that noone interferes with this call. One way for code to interfere with window creation is a hook. Are you (or a library you're using) calling [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx)?

Comment: DS_CONTROL did not change anything. GetLastError() returns 0. I have removed the ETC portion, and have verified that it is only related to the edittexts. The dialog has about 20 edittexts in it, and it does not matter which four+ i leave in, only 3 render and the fourth (presumably) throws the error. I do not believe SetWindowsHookEx is being called at all, but this I will have to verify.

Comment: `SetWindowsHookEx` can also set a *global hook*. Make sure that you do not have any tools installed in your system, that might induce bugs. To verify this, open your executable in *Dependency Walker*, note the dependencies, and match them against the *Modules* list in Visual Studio's debugger while debugging. Alternatively, set up a virtual machine with a clean OS install for testing.

Comment: The development is already being done in a VM, and across 3 different machines the problem persisted. I will have to take a look at the dependencies. Thanks.

Comment: Or, even easier, since you have the instruction pointer address printed out as the first value of the exception message, you can match that to the offending module. Visual Studio's *Modules* window has an *Address* column, displaying the memory range where the module resides. This may give you enough of a clue to take it from there.

Comment: Good idea. Looks like user32.dll is the one throwing the exception. Time to dig into this more

Comment: As another note, everything is still working fine in the Application file created when I build the solution. So this seems to be deeper than a simple library error.

Comment: Hard to understand why you won't make an MCVE. If you did then you'd isolate the problem yourself. At the moment we have a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Its inherited code with a large codebase. I wouldn't be using win32 unless I had to. Not a lot of options here, so I need to work around the current error.

Comment: `DlgProc()` is still wrong; it should return `INT_PTR`, not `LRESULT`. That shouldn't fix it, but it'll get rid of the need to cast to `DLGPROC`. Is your dialog procedure ever called before the crash?

Comment: Yup, the code reaches the DialogProc perfectly fine, and as I said, the same structure works 100% fine for Dialogs with less than 4 Edittexts. WM_INITDIALOG is never called, but presumably that is because the initialization fails on one of the Edittext controls.

Comment: Again, it's hard to understand why you won't make an MCVE. It's almost as if you don't want help.

Comment: @Jesavino - Could you please show your DlgProc? Alternatively, you can place a breakpoint on its first line and add a watch `msg,wm`. The `CreateDialog()` call will cause multiple messages to be sent to your DlgProc: `WM_SETFONT`, `WM_INITDIALOG`, and then some.Are you saying you never get `WM_INITDIALOG`? Then what are you doing in `WM_SETFONT` handler?